# is it possible to receive RSSI data from iBeacon much faster?

Tags: ibeacon, rssi, estimote

i know that recent apps can get the RSSI data continuously from beacon.
but i need to get the data much faster.

it may sounds weird that "much faster". 
but if you watch this video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B1J1YPQ5_g
(you can watch the video from 4:25)

you will see the scene that the app shows immediate changes of 3 colors on screen (red, green blue), when it approaches to one of each beacons.

actually, i tried to test my beacons accuracy like the way they did in Android.
but my app shows very slow color changes.

for example, when i need the RSSI value from 54 to 80, my app should continuously show it  on my screen like this 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, ..... 78, 79, 80 as i'm getting far away from beacons.

but in my test, it wasn't like that. it just showed RSSI values separately like 54, 57, 59, 77, 80.

i guess, the problem is that even if i continuously get the RSSI, i need to receive it much faster to show the changes of colors like the video.

is there any way to solve my problem??

am i missing something in here??

Answer (score 1):

you may change the advertising interval.
By decreasing that the beacon will transmit packets faster.
Note that it may increase the power consumption and reduce the battery life!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "much faster" it is unclear what you mean.  "Much faster" than what?

The Android iBeacon Library provides ranging callbacks every second with the latest RSSI reading from the beacon.  In the video, I did not see the color changing more than once per second, so from what I can tell, the library appears to provide RSSI updates fast enough to do what is shown on the video.

If you want to show different colors for different distances, you can either do it based on a range of the RSSI value or based on a range of the "accuracy" field, which is an estimated distance in meters derived from the RSSI value.

Answer (score 0):

In Estimote SDK you can change sampling frequency.

See [JavaDocs](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/) on BeaconManager#setForegroundScanPeriod